# How do I add a column to a dataframe with a repeating series of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say for the dataframe:

```
Ind  d1  d2  d3  
0      x0     x0     x0  
1      x1     x1     x1  
2      x2     x2     x2  
...  
n      xn     xn     xn
```

I want to add a new column such that the 1 2 3 4 5 pattern is repeated until n is reached. i.e.

```
Ind  d1  d2  d3  d4    
0      x0     x0     x0     1  
1      x1     x1     x1     2  
2      x2     x2     x2     3  
3      x3     x3     x3     4  
4      x4     x4     x4     5  
5      x5     x5     x5     1  
6      x6     x6     x6     2  
...  
n      xn     xn     xn     (1,2,3,4 or 5 depending on n)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Setup**
Consider the Pandas data frame `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list('abcdefghij'), (12, 3)),
    columns=['d1', 'd2', 'd3']
)

df

   d1 d2 d3
0   a  c  h
1   d  i  h
2   a  g  i
3   g  a  c
4   a  e  j
5   h  d  c
6   e  d  d
7   g  h  h
8   e  f  d
9   h  f  j
10  i  h  g
11  e  h  g
```

---

**Solution**
Try using modulo

```
df.assign(d4=np.arange(len(df)) % 5 + 1)

   d1 d2 d3  d4
0   a  c  h   1
1   d  i  h   2
2   a  g  i   3
3   g  a  c   4
4   a  e  j   5
5   h  d  c   1
6   e  d  d   2
7   g  h  h   3
8   e  f  d   4
9   h  f  j   5
10  i  h  g   1
11  e  h  g   2
```

**Extended Solution**
Easy to apply to repeating of anything.  Suppose I had an array of words `a`

```
a = np.array(['one', 'six', 'foot', 'red', 'big'])

df.assign(d4=a[np.arange(len(df)) % len(a)])

   d1 d2 d3    d4
0   a  c  h   one
1   d  i  h   six
2   a  g  i  foot
3   g  a  c   red
4   a  e  j   big
5   h  d  c   one
6   e  d  d   six
7   g  h  h  foot
8   e  f  d   red
9   h  f  j   big
10  i  h  g   one
11  e  h  g   six
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [@piRsquared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336654/pirsquared)'s data,

```
df['new'] = 0
np.put(df['new'], np.arange(len(df)), [1,2,3,4,5])
```

`df` is now:

```
   d1 d2 d3  new
0   i  j  i    1
1   a  e  a    2
2   d  j  i    3
3   i  a  a    4
4   c  j  d    5
5   i  a  h    1
6   h  d  c    2
7   a  e  a    3
8   a  f  i    4
9   a  h  f    5
10  d  b  d    1
11  b  c  c    2
```

Comment: Haven't see `np.put` before... is it like select?

Comment: Yeah, /mindblown a little bit!  Next you'll see me on an `np.put` campaign (-:

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  I think `np.put` should have a `cycle` inside .

Comment: Prefill with `0` and keep it `int`  `df['new'] = 0`

Comment: @piRSquared Ok, Let me fix it :-)

Comment: I love new things.   Nice Wen. +1

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
`np.tile`:

```
df

    A   B   C
0  13  11   2
1   8   8   6
2   7   6  13
3  13  16   4
4   3   1   3
5   2  27   9
6  20   1   2
7   5   3   9
8   0  10   1
9   1   7   4

np.tile(np.arange(1, 6), len(df) // 5 + 1)[:len(df)]
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Assign the result to a column, and you're good to go.

---

**Option 2**
`groupby` + `cumcount`:

```
df.groupby(df.index // 5 * 5).cumcount() + 1

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    1
6    2
7    3
8    4
9    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: why 5+1 in `np.tile(np.arange(1, 6), len(df) // 5 + 1)[:len(df)]`

Comment: @pyd Sorry? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I want to know why you're using 5+1. want to know whats happening in that line, pls explain

Comment: @pyd A little bit of mathemagic. I want to account for situations where the length of the dataframe isn't a perfect multiple of 5. If it is, then `np.tile(np.arange(1, 6), len(df) // 5)` is enough. But if it isn't, then you'll run into length mismatches. I'm trying to account for that.

Comment: but `np.tile(np.arange(1,6), len(df))[:len(df)]` itself gives the same output right ?

Comment: @pyd If `len(df)` is 51, then `np.tile` should give me 55 = `5 * (50 // 5 + 1 = 11)` from which I only take the first 51. Note that I only repeat 11 times (that much is sufficient), not 51 times. Hope it's clear now.